# Font not showing properly in email

Tags: php, html, css

I used 'Raleway' font as the font of email body in php email, but the text is not showing in 'Raleway' in email client. The style for the text is given inline.

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


<div style="font-family: Raleway, sans-serif">
//Content
</div>
```

Comment: Use `font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;` with `' '` not how you wrote it

Comment: Done..but font is showing differently in email body and when the same is created as a '.html' page

Comment: Use `HTML` email content.

Comment: Lets see how your `php` mailing code is like. Did you specify `content-type = text/html`?

Comment: What is your email client? Many programs (e.g. Outlook) can strip out custom fonts for readability.

Comment: I am using Yii mailing. Client is gmail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

External fonts just won't work in almost all email clients. You'd be better off using web safe fonts in your email. And a heads up, lot of CSS properties won't work either and style will have to be included inline. I didn't know this at first, But I've been creating HTML emails for over a month now, so, don't waste a lot of time trying to get it to work.

Here are a list of CSS properties that work with different email clients:
https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

And here are a list of web safe fonts:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_websafe_fonts.asp

Answer (score 1):

Try this code,

```
<div style="font-family: 'Raleway';">
//Content
</div>
```

Comment: Done..but font is showing differently in email and when the same is created as a '.html' page

Comment: Custom fonts will not work there (no-go for google fonts).

Answer (score 1):

External fonts/links are best avoided in email.  You can set the font inline in the chance that they have that font installed already with a backup font chosen like this:

```
   <td style="font-family: 'Raleway', Arial, sans-serif;></td>
```

However it should be noted that the bulk would display the backup font. but this just shows it as a first option in case.